Gas Water Heater Electrical Requirements
With modern Gas Water heaters using electrical connections, I would like to know if any one could point me to the code for the installation of electrical next to the Gas Hot Water heater.
1: What is the required outlet type - special sealed unit, direct connect wiring, placement?
2: Disconnect switch hazardous location - type  and placement?
In a nutshell does there need to be a disconnect at the unit , does it have to be hard wired, if connectable what kind of plug outlet is required or will standard work ?
I do know the Gas Water heater has to have pilot light or ignition source at least 18 inches off the ground [IPC], therefore I do know that electrical should also be above that level using the same reasoning of ignition source.
I have searched for the NFPA70 code sections but I can not seem to find anything in this regards.

I do not know code.  Usually the disconnect is away from the heater and easy to reach.  Most heaters are hard wired, not plugged in except tiny ones.  Local regulations will be what you go by, so your local building department will have the best answers for you.

AFIK gas fired tank water heaters do not require mains voltage. They have a standing pilot light which is lighted by a piezo electric sparker. The energy of the spark is supplied by the push on the piezoelectric element. Modern gas fired tankless heaters generally do require mains voltage to operate the controls. But there are some gas fired tankless heaters for off-grid use that employ a battery to operate controls. My house has an old Bosch tanless WH which does not require mains power nor does it have a battery. It has a standing pilot light which is lit by a piezoelectric sparker.

Is this a tank or a tankless WH?

@JimStewart - I appreciate your help but you are a little behind the times. GasPacks and WIFI controllers and power venting require AC power to operate. GasPacks allow your Tank to run on-demand and not continuous Pilot flame (no need to waste gas when tank water is up to temp). WiFi control allows you to monitor and adjust the temperature remotely - in winter time if you have a hydronic heating system you might want water temp setting adjusted upwards.

Ken, thanks for the pleasantly polite correction. I am about to turn 80 and I increasingly find I am behind on developments. I thought a standing pilot flame in a gas fired tank WH was OK because the heat would be absorbed by the water in the tank, as opposed to a standing pilot in a tankless WH. So I take it you have a gas fired tank WH?

What state is this to be installed in? In at least one US state the cable to provide power to a gas fired water heater must be 3-conductor plus ground, at least 10 AWG copper fed through a 20-A breaker, even if one conductor is not needed currently. I presume this is to allow for ready transition to a heat pump WH.

@JimStewart 80 awesome!! Florida - nothing crazy like CA, WA, OR , NJ, or NY.
Gas Water Heater (Tank style). I could understand 3 wire + G 10AWG for 240V electric - but not for Gas units unless they are power vented with 240V motor (perhaps due to efficiency). Considering this is a 120Volt 15/20 amp circuit requirement there is not a need for the additional conductor. Heat Pump units - surprisingly I have seen 120V units (I wouldn't ). HP units are noisy it might have some advantages if I were to suck in my attic air in summer but not so much in winter when I have heavier use.

What county in Florida is this property located in? The cost of installing a  3-conductor 10 AWG copper cable is not much more than installing a 2-conductor 12 AWG cable and would allow later installation of a heat pump tank WH without installing a new cable.

Why would I ever want to install a heat pump unit? I have a hydronic heating system and a heat pump unit will not reach water temp of 140-180 degrees, further it will never have the first hour rating or heat recovery rate required.

Probably Florida will not discontinue residental gas service for your lifetime, so there would be no reason for you to install a larger cable than you need for the gas controls. Hydronic heating so baseboard, under floor, or forced air with ductwork?
